# Reference Request: Books containing examples of Applied Theory/Math

Tags: theory

I recently came across a blog post that introduced the term "[Bayesian Spam Filtering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naive_Bayes_spam_filtering)" and talked about how this was the approach behind spam filtering for emails.

I also remember a paper (perhaps it was [this](https://dl.acm.org/doi/10.1145/571697.571723)?) discussing how Game Theory is involved in packet routing, or how it used for Resource Allocation in Cloud Computing. Also, I recall a university course on Formal Methods, and how they're used in Software Engineering.

I am looking for books which talk about how concepts from Mathematics or CS Theory are actually applied in every day technology.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any good textbook will at least mention and ideally discuss everyday applications of the subject matter whenever possible. For example, the excellent [*Artificial Intelligence: A Modern Approach*](http://aima.cs.berkeley.edu/) by Russell and Norvig does this throughout.

More specialized books will of course tend to have deeper discussions of the applications. What is one 30-page chapter in Russell and Norvig is a whole book by Sutton and Barto: [*Reinforcement Learning: An Introduction*](http://incompleteideas.net/sutton/book/the-book.html) (free pdf at the link, courtesy of the authors). Have a look at chapter 16 for some fascinating applications.

There are also books that start with an application, i.e. a practical problem, and then develop all the theory necessary to solve it. One of my favorites in this category is [*In Pursuit of the Traveling Salesman: Mathematics at the Limits of Computation*](https://press.princeton.edu/books/paperback/9780691163529/in-pursuit-of-the-traveling-salesman) by William Cook.

Comment: Just went through the table of contents for _In Pursuit of the Travelling Salesman,_ and I have to say, I think it comes closest to what I had in mind. Now, if only there was a book that was a _compendium_ of such other books (this one for TSP, maybe something else for Game Theory, etc.).

Answer (score 0):

You might be interested in [Math for Programmers](https://www.manning.com/books/math-for-programmers) which has some interesting approaches to programming by pure math. In retrospect, [A Programmer's Introduction to Mathematics](https://www.amazon.in/Programmers-Introduction-Mathematics-Jeremy-Kun/dp/1727125452) teaches math using programming, which might be helpful if you want to learn it backwards.